# Inject mock into methods field

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, ejb, jboss-arquillian

I want to inject mock object into method's fields in testing bean. 
We have sth. like:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class TestedBean implements TestedBeanInterface
{
  public OtherClass testedMethod { 
     private ClassIWantToMock necessaryField = new ClassIWantToMock(); 
     return necessaryField.doThingsImpossibleToDoAtTest(); 
  }  
}
```

And that bean, I am testing in this way:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TripPlannerFactoryBeanTest {

   @Deployment
   public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
      //
   }

   @EJB(mappedName = "java:module/TestedBean!ab.abc.abcd.TestedBean")
   TestedBean testedBean;

   @Test
   public void testMethodOfTestedBean(){
   testedBean.testedMethod();
   }
}
```

It is possible to mock ClassIWantToMock() without any changes in TestedBean code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to actual mock frameworks like Mockito? Or what exactly do you want to achieve/test?

The simple answer to your question is no. As long as you instantiate the instance directly in *testedMethod* there is no way to mock it.

Could you not inject the class instead, but of course you would need to change the code. Depending on what you want to test a library like Byteman can help, especially if you are trying to test error cases.